# Возможна ли работа работа с базой данных на С++ без SQL запросов?

Tags: c++, sql

Есть некая СУБД (думаю не важно какая) и при этом достаточно большого объема - миллионы записей в разных таблицах, у которой по некоторым причинам запросы выполняются неимоверно долго - от 2х часов. Есть ли возможность работы с БД прямо на сервере через высоко оптимизированное С++ приложение которое будет брать данные не по SQL запросу а прямо с дисков и формировать их на вывод? например как временную таблицу для вывода клиенту.

P.S. Да я натыкался на статьи которые это как раз и обсуждают, но конкретно примеров я не смог найти

Comment: Возможность конечно же есть. Никто не мешает вам написать такое приложение. Остается вопрос, а зачем? Возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону оптимизации запросов или архитектуры? Почему вы уверены, что сможете написать работу с файлами БД лучше самих разработчиков этой БД ?

Comment: Например как [эта статья](https://xakep.ru/2015/06/26/academy-cpp-197/). Там обсуждаются тонкости оптимизации, но не инструменты взятия данных.

Comment: Откровенно - замучитесь **свою** субд писать...

Comment: вы бы все же добавили информацию о своей БД

Comment: @Viktorov это скорее в академических целях, вряд ли мне позволяет такое написать в ближайшем будущем, но хотя бы буду знать. Да и проблема такая стоит, потому что большая часть таких процедур ставится на ночное время

Comment: Я глянул статью по диагональке. Все что там написано, по сути - это СИ++ быстрый. Бесспорно, скорее всего можно написать код, который будет читать файлы БД и делать из них JSON'ы быстрее базы. Однако, разница может быть совершенно незначительной и вовсе не факт, что лично вы сможете написать такой код за приемлемое время. В случае вашей задачи я по прежнему рекомендовал бы попробовать оптимизировать работу запросов.Миллионы строк - это не так и много в современных реалиях

Comment: @Viktorov на данный момент MS SQL Server, но как я слышал в некоторых организациях(в числе которой я работаю) могут запретить использование продуктов MS, и что будет через год два неизвестно.

Comment: @Viktorov и все же есть процедуры и запросы которые выполняются по 4-8 часов, и в дневное время такие запросы бывают выполняются. Да миллионы это относительно немного, но в сумме думаю выйдет на миллиарды - только по одному приложению у коллеги в суме 4 миллиарда вышло, хоть он и фильтрует в итоге

Comment: @Harry я думаю писать не полноценную субд а конкретно описать запросы которые очень долго выполняются

Comment: На мой взгляд правильный подход к оптимизации выглядит так: Сначала выясняется, откуда у проблемы растут ноги, в вашем случае, почему же эти запросы выполняются так долго(смотреть планы, индексы). Потом предпринимается попытка ускорить запросы использую существующие инструменты(собственно ваш MS SQL). И только потом стоит думать о том, как используя Си++ напрямую ползать в файлы. Так же надо понимать, что любое обновление БД может сломать ваш код на Си++ и его придется дорабатывать.

Comment: @Viktorov согласен, но я это хотел сделать в пробных целях чтобы бегло сравнить скорость работы. В принципе я смог сформировать поисковый запрос исходя из ваших вопросов и смог найти примеры, Спасибо :)

Comment: Не обижайтесь, но базы данных (тем более старые, проверенные) пишут люди, не в пример более опытные, чем задающие (и многие отвечающие) подобные вопросы на различных площадках. Вы не сможете сделать быстрее, чем работает БД. Можно ли это сделать в принципе? Какую-то частную задачу, наверное, можно. В общем виде — вряд ли.

Comment: Скорее всего надо поменять что-то в архитектуре проекта. Писать код, который лезет в данные прямо с диска - Брррр. Найдите узкое место и оптимизируйте его. На крайний случай делайте срезы и храните в опер. памяти в своем приложении.

Comment: @Ackbar Я понимаю, что не полноценную. Но просто продраться через формат файлов базы данных с выбиранием нужной информации с последующим ее отбором etc etc - не с той стороны вы беретесь. Тем более что лезть - даже просто для чтения - в чужие активно используемые файлы - уже чревато проблемами. По-моему, вы подходите к задаче не с той стороны...

Comment: Ну вот представьте себе - вы потратили N человеко-месяцев и умудрились написать приложение , которое выполняет читает одну таблицу (вариант в котором вы напишите полноценный оптимизатор запросов я даже не рассматриваю - такие вещи пишут команды с многолетним опытом) быстрее, а разработчики СУБД в очередном релизе изменили формат данных и ваше приложение уже не работает...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу сказать пару слов про `PostgreSQL`, но общий посыл будет одинаковый для всех СУБД и уже изложен в комментариях к вопросу.

Механизм [`extensions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend.html) в `PostgreSQL` позволяет написать компилируемый код и вмешиваться в работу СУБД. Не вижу причин, мешающих из `extension` реализовать более низкоуровневое чтение данных требуемым способом. `extension` в `postgresql` может очень многое сделать.

Для общения с приложением чуток `SQL` при этом скорей всего останется - но просто потому, что реализовать передачу данных на клиент проще через `SQL`, в частности в формате вызова хранимой процедуры:

```
select * from my_extension_function_read_data();
```

Не думайте, однако, что это будет просто. Некоторый объём `SQL`-запросов есть даже в ядре этой СУБД - например материализованные представления строятся на самом деле с использованием `SQL`. Через `SQL` же, сюрприз, сейчас реализованы проверки `foreign key`.

Если вы захотите использовать индекс - то будьте добры сходить в `pg_catalog`, найти там самостоятельно подходящий индекс и с использованием `access method API` к нему обратиться подходящим (!) способом - я имею в виду, что есть несколько возможных способов использовать один и тот же индекс  и не для всех `access method` все эти способы реализованы. Если вы захотите сделать сортировку - будьте добры её делать самостоятельно или разбираться, как она сделана в штатном `executor`, в том числе что делать если у вас данных больше чем памяти. А уж если хотите что-то переджойнить или аггрегировать...

Это, разумеется, если говорить об использовании штатных средств манипуляции данными СУБД, которые скрывают за собой ещё много деталей в том числе чтения данных с диска в память и дают простые абстракции менеджера блокировок. С конкурентным доступом надо по-прежнему быть аккуратным, но их не надо реализовывать заново и думать, как подружить с активностью остальной базы.

Даже не упоминаю об идее читать напрямую датафайлы с дисков. СУБД считает себя монопольным владельцем своих датафайлов и считает вправе их менять любым образом сообразно своим алгоритмам ни с кем дополнительно не советуясь (и что хуже того - может некоторое время *не* менять файлы, накапливая изменения исключительно в памяти - т.е. из файлов вы можете целостную картину не получить вообще). Структура же этих датафайлов может требовать неожиданной дополнительной ручной работы - например, длинные тексты могут лежать в других датафайлах, да ещё в сжатом виде. Или продолжают храниться уже удалённые колонки (не говоря о множестве удалённых строк), что надо проверять по другим датафайлам и воспроизводить заметный кусок логики СУБД. А затем каждый релиз (возможно даже минорный) проверять, что изменилось в этом отношении.

---

Основной вопрос и ответ, впрочем, в другом. Если вы знаете, как эффективно получать требуемые данные - то значительно разумнее не хардкодить механику планировщика и переизобретать `executor`, а разобраться, как попросить вашу СУБД использовать именно такой план запроса и понять почему обычно планировщик от этого плана отказывается. Универсальный планировщик запросов работает на статистике, математике и чёрной магии - и вполне может ошибаться по разным причинам. Или же ошибаться можете как раз вы в своих предположениях, а планировщик выбрал более подходящий план. Или же СУБД настроена странно (тот же `postgresql` из коробки поставляется с конфигом чтобы запуститься и никому не мешать, а не эффективно использовать имеющееся железо). Или же вы просто написали что-нибудь странное с точки зрения планировщика в запросе, что тот не понимает как переписать. Например, не все планировщики понимают, что `where id + 5 = 10` эквивалентно `where id = 10 + 5` - в результате первый запрос будет делать полный просмотр таблицы, а второй - сможет использовать индекс.